# Python connect 4 play function

Tags: python, python-3.x, connect-four

I'm making a connect4 game for a class and im running into an error with my play function that I'm having difficulties figuring out.

```
def play(grid,column,checker):
    
    counter = 0
    for x in grid[0]:
        counter += 1
    print(counter)
    if counter > column-1 :
        for row in reversed(grid):
            if row[column-1] == "empty":
                row[column-1] = checker
                print(True)
                return True,grid,checker
    else:
        print(False)
        return False  , grid , checker
```

The problem occurs at line 9 (if row[column-1] == "empty") and I keep getting typeError 'int' opject is not subscriptable.
grid is a global variable returned from a different function.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: It's saying `row` is an `int`.

Comment: perhaps you want to pass `grid` as list of lists and you are merely passing a list, so your row (which you expect to be a list) is an integer. And it tries to access row[column-1], which you cant do for an integer, you get the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is actually in the different function `grid` is returned from. You must have made some mistake there, which causes that different function return something of the form `[1, 6, 3, 8, 3]`, whereas your `play` function assumes something in the form of `[[1, 5, 6, 2, 10], [1, 5, 6, 2, 10], [1, 5, 6, 2, 10], [1, 5, 6, 2, 10]]`.

Comment: Thanks! I had edited my grid function to try and return multiple values which had messed everything up without me realizing.

Comment: @808Blues no problem !